# mamp on mac - start/stop mamp server on schedule to download remote files

Tags: macos, mamp, mamp-pro

I have MAMP installed on my Macbook. I would like to download remote backups to my Macbook's external harddrive weekly.

I don't have MAMP running all the time though, so ideally I'd want my macbook to:

1. Automatically start up MAMP at a scheduled time interval
2. Execute the script I created to download the remote backup
   files
3. Shut down MAMP again.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: A server might not be suitable for downloading files. Better create a shell script for downloading and then run it on an interval using launchd

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert great, that works! No need for MAMP at all